# Plot SinglePredictionBands associated with a FittedModel (e.g. LinearModelFit) that is supplied as a variable

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fitting, variable-definitions, function-construction

I am puzzled about how to plot the `SinglePredictionBands` associated with a `FittedModel` (*e.g*. `LinearModelFit`) that is supplied as a variable.

The reasons I am interested in this are:

- I want to create some plot definitions to reuse;
- I want to include the graphics as arguments to `Manipulate`.

Please see the following code.  The embedded comments explain what works and what doesn't.

```
dataTest = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};

(* Explicit code works:  both the fit and the bounds are plotted.  The name of the dummy variable doesn't matter here.  *)
lm = LinearModelFit[dataTest[[1 ;; 3]], {xVar}, {xVar}]
spb[xVar_] = lm["SinglePredictionBands"]
Plot[{lm[x], spb[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Explicit (argument x)"]
Plot[{lm[xVar], spb[xVar]}, {xVar, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Explicit (argument xVar)"]

(* This delayed-evaluation code either plots only the fit (with x) or nothing (with xVar). *)
lmFn1[aaa_, bbb_] := LinearModelFit[dataTest[[aaa ;; bbb]], {xVar}, {xVar}]
spbFn1[fit_][xVar_] := fit["SinglePredictionBands"]
Plot[{lmFn1[1, 3][x], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument x)"]
Plot[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][xVar]}, {xVar, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument xVar)"]

(* This hybrid code either plots only the fit (with x) or only the bounds (with xVar). *)
Plot[{lmFn1[1, 3][x], spbFn1[lm][x]}, {x, 0, 5},  PlotLabel -> "Delayed2 (argument x)"]
Plot[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lm][xVar]}, {xVar, 0, 5},  PlotLabel -> "Delayed2 (argument xVar)"]

(* I had also tried the following, although it would be inefficient, because fitting the same data is repeated.  *)
(* This alternative delayed-evaluation code either plots only the fit (with x) or nothing (with xVar).*)
pFn1[i_, j_] := Plot[{lmFn1[i, j][x], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Delayed3 (argument x)"]
pFn2[i_, j_] := Plot[{lmFn1[i, j][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][xVar]}, {xVar, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Delayed3 (argument xVar)"]
pFn1[1, 3]
pFn2[1, 3]
```

Some of the problematic code generates errors like
"`LinearModelFit::ivar: {0.000102143} is not a valid variable.`" (what's visible is actually "`LinearModelFit: {0.000102143} is not a valid variable.`"), and some of it fails silently.

I've spent time trying many different configurations, and none worked.  I'd appreciate an explanation of why the above-indicated lines of code don't work, and how they could be improved (preferably a simple way to improve them).

As a final aside, I haven't yet combined this with a `Manipulate` statement, but I am envisaging doing it with a subsequent `Dynamic` statement.

—DIV

P.S.  After spending time debugging I did find a handful of posts on possibly related themes

- [Manipulating a Plot of a FittedModel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156133/manipulating-a-plot-of-a-fittedmodel)
- [How to pass a symbol name to a function with any of the Hold attributes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/how-to-pass-a-symbol-name-to-a-function-with-any-of-the-hold-attributes)
- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia)

But that was not sufficient to clarify to me what the underlying problem is, nor how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extended comment that points out some issues that some might consider coding errors so you shouldn't be surprised if this question is closed.  (I'm on the fence about that right now.)

Your definition of `spbFn1` with `lmFn1`

```
lmFn1[aaa_, bbb_] := LinearModelFit[dataTest[[aaa ;; bbb]], {xVar}, {xVar}]
spbFn1[fit_][xVar_] := fit["SinglePredictionBands"]
```

doesn't change the name of the predictor variable.  For example,

```
spbFn1[lmFn1[1,3]][x]
```

gets you

```
{0.428571 + 0.428571 xVar - 12.7062 Sqrt[1.95918 - 0.653061 xVar + 0.244898 xVar^2], 
 0.428571 + 0.428571 xVar + 12.7062 Sqrt[1.95918 - 0.653061 xVar + 0.244898 xVar^2]}
```

So

```
spbFn1[fit_] := fit["SinglePredictionBands"]
Plot[{lmFn1[1, 3][x], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]] /. xVar -> x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument x)"]
```

gets you

[image: Prediction and 95% single confidence bands]

For

```
Plot[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]}, {xVar, 0, 5},  
  PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument xVar)"]
```

to "work" you'll need to use `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]}], {xVar, 0, 5},
  PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument xVar)"]
```

[image: Alternative to get prediction and single prediction bands]

This as you see gets you two different colors for the upper and lower single prediction bands.  That can be fixed with adding the `PlotStyle` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, JimB.  Thanks for the advice, and thanks for taking the time to give the question the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Your solution is actually quite like the suggestion by b3m2a1 (in the first link at the bottom of my original question) to prefix the fit names with `Evaluate@`.  I had attempted this, and couldn't get it to work.  
Your syntax, and that of b3m2a1 and Karsten 7 (`Evaluated -> True`) are all now working with variable `xVar`.  I guess that before I'd tried it with the wrong dummy variable name (`x`).  In building up the code I originally wrote a version of pFn1 and pFn2 that only contained the fit (not the bounds), and they only work if you DON'T use `xVar` as the dummy variable.  (Why???)

Comment: While the proposed solution solves the immediate problem, and is indeed simple to implement, I still cannot understand the logic.  Why with the `/. xVar -> x` inserted is `Evaluate` no longer needed?  `/.` is documented as `ReplaceAll`:  is this automatically implying `Evaluate`?  (If so, are there other trivial operations that implicitly invoke `Evaluate` too?)  Why with `Evaluate@` or `Evaluate[...]` are the bounds printed as two separately coloured curves, whereas with the `Evaluated -> True` rule set within `Plot` the bounds print as single 'object' with a single colour?  ...

Comment: ...  The following all yield exactly the same output when invoked outside of `Plot`:  `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]` and `Evaluate[spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]]` and `Evaluate@spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]`, which is `spbFn1[\!\(\*
TagBox[   ...   Selectable->True]\)]`.  I cannot inspect the equivalent effect of `Evaluated -> True` outside of `Plot`.  Incidentally, `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][xVar]` *etc.* and `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][x]` *etc.* instead all yield `{0.428571 + 0.428571 xVar - 
  12.7062 Sqrt[1.95918 - 0.653061 xVar + 0.244898 xVar^2], 
    ....   }`.  It *looks* different.  ...

Comment: Sorry for writing so many comments...  I just noticed actually you might have a typo in your solution.  I didn't notice at first because I was making small edits in my Notebook.  Actually `Plot[Evaluate[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]}], {xVar, 0, 5},
  PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument xVar)"]` does not work properly for me:  it only plots the fit, not the bounds.  However replacing `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]` with either `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][x]` or `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][xVar]` does yield the output you presented (plotting the bounds in two distinct colours, which should be easy to fix).

Comment: I try to answer one of my own questions (see above):  "*I originally wrote a version of pFn1 and pFn2 that only contained the fit (not the bounds), and they only work if you DON'T use xVar as the dummy variable. (Why???)*"  I guess writing `lmFn1[1, 3][x]` substitutes `xVar` with `x`, so maybe this is an example of one of the "*trivial operations that implicitly invoke Evaluate too*" that I'd speculated about.  Whereas in `lmFn1[1, 3][xVar]` there's no substitution made.

Comment: Update:  while `Evaluated -> True` is a valid option for `Plot`, it isn't for `LogPlot`.  By Toutatis *Mathematica* makes itself hard to use!

Comment: `[x]` is necessary for `lmFn1[1,3]` but why do you think you need `[x]` attached to `spbFn1`?

Comment: I don't know the underlying reason, but `Plot[Evaluate[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]]}], {xVar, 0, 5},
  PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument xVar)"]` does not plot the bounds in *Mathematica* 11.3; it only plots the fit.  However, `Plot[Evaluate[{lmFn1[1, 3][xVar], spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3]][xVar]}], {xVar, 0, 5},
  PlotLabel -> "Delayed1 (argument xVar)"]` does plot the bounds, as well as the fit.  (With this code the bounds are plotted in two distinct colours, which should be easy to fix.)

Comment: ...For completeness, neither `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3][xVar]]` nor `spbFn1[lmFn1[1, 3][xVar]][xVar]` plot the bounds.

Comment: I still don't see why `Evaluate` is required.  The output of the Single Prediction Bounds is two polynomials in braces.  But I can plot `Plot[{3 + x^2, 1 - x^2}, {x, 0, 3}]` (in 2 colours), or `polyFn1[x_] := {3 + x^2, 1 - x^2}; Plot[polyFn1[x], {x, 0, 3}]` (in 1 colour), or `polynomList1 = {3 + x^2, 1 - x^2}; Plot[polynomList1, {x, 0, 3}]` (in 2 colours).  None of them need `Evaluate`.  *Mathematica*'s documentation for `Evaluate` and `Hold` is not helpful for this, and the documentation for `Plot` and `HoldAll` is not much better.  Nor does it help that `hold` means something else in MATLAB!